# Heroku - retrieve remote changes of JSON file

Tags: json, git, heroku

My site that heroku hosts takes user inputs and update a json file on a remote server. I should have probably stored in a database. It's a better solution. But is there any way I can download the most up to date Json files on the Heroku remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't offer any mechanism to commit files directly on the server, or to copy files from the server. One of the main reasons is [its ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

If the file is accessible over the web you might be able to download it from your browser, but whatever file you created may not be there anymore. You're right that a database is a better choice.